# Promise.resolve return undefined from jest mock function

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I have a function which makes API call and based on what would return by the first API call it makes the second API call. But the first API always returns undefined

```
getTotalCount = async () => {
    const { showCountCallBack, showCount } = this.props;
    try {
      const response = await showCount();

      const count = isEmpty(response.result);

      if (count) {
        console.log(" success");
      } else {
        showCountCallBack({ ...this.state });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };
```

```
describe("component", () => {
  let shallowComponent;
  let shallowComponentInstance;
  const showCountMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ result: [] }));

  const showCountCallBackMock = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ result: [] }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    showCountMock.mockReset();

    shallowComponent = shallowWithTheme(
      <Component
        showCount={showCountMock}
        showCountCallBack={showCountCallBackMock}
      />
    );
    shallowComponentInstance = shallowComponent.instance();
  });

  it("viewMapping", () => {
    shallowComponentInstance.getTotalCount();
    expect(showCountMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(showCountCallBackMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After struggling for hours. I have found the cause. It was `mockReset` causing this issue.

It reset return value as well. so I just removed the `mockReset` from code. Better to use `mockClear` here